# Unwind from a VC to a TabBarController and change tab index

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have the following Storyboard layout:

[image: diagram of Storyboard layout]

When the app starts it goes to `HomeView VC` at TabIndex 1.

In the `HomeView` I have a button and I segue to the `TestView` using

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStartTest", sender: self)
```

Now I want to go from `TestView` to `HistoryView`. The only way I can see to do that right now is to create a segue from `TestView` to `TabBarController`. This brings up `HomeView` with Tab Bar intact. I do this from `TestView` using

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "testToRes", sender: self)
```

However, that leaves me on `HomeView`, I need `HistoryView`.

The research I've done points to using Unwind and detecting where segue came from and acting accordingly.

I'm using the latest Xcode with Swift 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your `HomeViewController` like this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    var goToHistory = false

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if goToHistory {
            goToHistory = false

            // Use whichever index represents the HistoryViewController
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindAndGoToHistory(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        goToHistory = true
    }
}
```

In your `TestViewController`, either:

1. Wire a `UIButton` to the `Exit` icon to unwind to `unwindAndGoToHistory:`.

   **OR**
2. Create a programmatic unwind by wiring from the `View Controller` icon to the `Exit` icon (again selecting `unwindAndGoToHistory:`), and then find this segue in the *Document Outline* view and give it an *identifier* such as `"unwindToHistory"` in the *Attributes Inspector*. When you're ready to segue, trigger it with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToHistory", sender: self)`.

Then, when the unwind segue is triggered, iOS will pop the `TestViewController` and call `unwindAndGoToHistory()`.  In there, `goToHistory` gets set to `true`.  Afterwards, `viewWillAppear()` will be triggered.  Since `goToHistory` is now `true`, the code will set the `selectedIndex` of the `tabBarController` to switch to the `HistoryViewController`'s tab.

> **Note:** This will show the unwind animation back to `HomeViewController`, then the view will automatically switch to `HistoryViewController`.  If
>   instead you'd like to switch to `HistoryViewController` immediately with no
>   animation, override `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. It helped me understand the mechanics of it for future use. One point further to this, would it be possible to go STRAIGHT to the TabIndex1. TabIndex0 briefly appears before moving to 1. Ideally I'd like to go straight to 1. If I create a segue that bypasses the TabViewController the HistoryView does appear but loses the TabBar at the bottom, if that makes sense.

Comment: Did you try overriding `viewWillAppear` like in my **Note:**?

Answer (score 0):

To go from TestView to HistoryView, should be something along these lines:

```
// From TestView to HomeView(0)
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
// Change the active tab in the tabcontroller
(navigationController?.presentingViewController as? UITabBarController)?.selectedIndex = 1
```